# UART on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: raspberry-pi

I got a new version of Raspberry -  Pi 4 (a previous was Pi 2). 
The old code doesn't work. Although it opens the file descriptor

```
uart_fd = open("/dev/ttyAMA0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NONBLOCK);
```

and I get no errors.

I check it

```
raspi-gpio get 0-15
GPIO 14: level=1 fsel=2 alt=5 func=TXD1 pull=NONE
GPIO 15: level=1 fsel=2 alt=5 func=RXD1 pull=UP
```

And then

```
ls -l /dev/serial*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 5 Jan  6 13:43 /dev/serial0 -> ttyS0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Jan  6 13:43 /dev/serial1 -> ttyAMA0
```

So I assume /dev/ttyAMA0 is good to go but when I try to send or receive - nothing happens.

going further - ssize_t sent = write ( uart_fd ,  "hello " , 5);
sent = 0  - nothing was sent.

well...I open another port

uart_fd = open("/dev/serial0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);

now I get gibberish no matter what baud rate I choose.

Comment: Is serial enabled using `raspi-config`?

Comment: Interfacing Options->Serial->shell no, serial port yes. I suppose it's enabled.

Comment: You might get better answers over on https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com.